# Best way to rotate Django.QuerySet

Tags: python, django

I want to rotate my QuerySet like collections.deque.[rotate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque.rotate).
Now i do it like this:

```
def do_rotate(queryset, n)
    my_list = list(queryset)
    return my_list[n:] + my_list[:n]
```

How i can do it better?

Comment: Why not use an actual `deque` instead of a `list`, as in `deque(queryset)`?

Comment: What are you intending to do with it? are you trying to order your queryset in a particular way?

Comment: @Sayse usually, queryset is a queryset of users, and i want get user whose birthday is today and show him first in slider

Comment: @Selcuk i want to know, can i do it without deque and my hack, i want to use QuerySet methods after rotate

Comment: No. Querysets are lazily evaluated, meaning that it fetches the next record from the database when you ask for it. That's why you can't order it in your Python code without forcing it to evaluate using `list()` or similar. You have to perform the ordering on the database side, by using a clever (possibly chained) `order_by` clause.